# Python: Necessito obter a coordenada y dada a coordenada x

Tags: python, plot

Boa tarde!
x = [0, 5]
y = [2, 4]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

Obtenho a seguinte figura.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como obtenho o valor da coordenada y para a coordenada x igual a 2.5?

Obrigado.

Comment: Parece uma questão matemática. Pouco código, poderia compartilhar mais? Logicamente você deveria trabalhar com uma matriz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import polyfit
```

Definindo X e Y conhecidos

```
X = [0, 5] 
Y = [2, 4]
```

Calculando os coeficientes

```
m, b = polyfit(X, Y, deg=1)
```

Novo x para o calculo

```
x = 2.5
```

Equação da reta *y = mx + b*

```
y = m * x + b
```

Plotando

```
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.plot(x, y, 'go')
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]